# Динамическое дерево на ExtJs 3

Tags: дерево, extjs

Здравствуйте! Можете привести  пример динамического дерева на `extjs 3` (хотелось бы увидеть как выглядит клиентская и серверная части).

Answer (score 1):

Посмотри пример на Ext JS4:[Ext.tree.Panel. Деревья](http://metanit.com/web/extjs/7.6.php) может и к третьей версии подойдет